# .NET MAUI iOS won't deploy to iOS simulator once Keychain Sharing Entitlement is enabled

Tags: ios, .net, maui, entitlements

I'm developing a .NET MAUI application and I need to store an access token using the SecureStorage API. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=macios) guide from the Microsoft Documentation which states that the Keychain Entitlement should be added when deploying to the iOS simulator.

However, once the Entitlement is enabled if I try to run the app from Visual Studio for Mac I get the following error: `Could not find any available provisioning for MauiApp on iOS`.

Despite the error message is clear, I am not able to find any clear information about what am I supposed to do in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried [Automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=vs)?

Comment: I tried to set automatic provisioning inside Platforms/iOS/Info.plist but once set it asks for a Team which I don't have since (I guess) I am not enrolled in developer program. Manual provisioning instead works but, as soon as I set the keychain-group entry in the keychain-sharing option, then the app won't compile.

Comment: May i ask what is the version of Visual Studio for mac and XCode?

Comment: Sure, I'm running XCode 14.2 and Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview v17.6. I know XCode 14.3 is the latest version but I still run monterey on my machine so I'm not able to upgrade to the latest version yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a Apple Dev account, you could use XCode to apply free provisioning. You could refer to [Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos)(also works for MAUI but with a little difference).

To conclude, there are following steps:

1.[Use Xcode to create a signing identity and provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos#use-xcode-to-create-a-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile)

Create a XCode project with any Bundle Identifier you want. Enable **Automatically manage signing**. Select your Personal team if don't have other accounts. Then XCode will create the provisioning file for you.

2.[Deploy your Maui app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos#deploy-your-xamarinios-app)

Bundle Identifier of Maui project should be identical to the Bundle ID of XCode project you just created. Also select the provisioning file created by XCode.

Then you could run your Maui project.

Hope it works.

Comment: By following these steps I was able to deploy the application on both the iOS simulator and my own device. However, once I use the SecureStorage API on the simulator (which is the only thing I really need to do) despite I added the Entitlement I get a runtime exception saying that the Entitlement is missing. I also know from the documentation that the Entitlement is needed only when using the simulator, so I am really confused.

Comment: Re-sourcing the Entitlments.plist file on iOS bundle signing options on VS project options did the trick and now I'm able to use the SecureStorage API on the simulator. Still a bit overwhelmed by all the steps required to use such a simple feature but your help was highly appreciated. Thank you so much for your time. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can understand your feelings.